# Accidental "sudo rm -rf /*" on 32 GB USB 3.0

Tags: linux-mint, data-recovery

I have just executed `sudo rm -rf /*` for 2 secs on my 32GB SanDisk 3.0 USB.

I have Linux Mint 20.3 Una installed and I thought it would ask for sudo confirmation before executing the command but I forgot I recently had installed an application with sudo perms in the terminal a few minutes ago. I installed Linux Mint on my 32 GB USB (USB 3.0) and it ran the command for approximately 2 seconds, plus its read and write speed is kinda slow so maybe not everything has been wiped.

Can you please suggest some data I should? It doesn't boot anymore btw. (I absolutely will be backing up the whole home directory) And can I copy the whole `/usr` directory for restoring my programs (`/bin` directory seems to have been deleted) and are there any more directories that are used by applications to store their data that I can/should backup? If you know what I mean.

I have started my installation media and mounted my USB.
It still has these folders, symlinks and a swapfile:
`boot` `dev` `etc` `home` **`lib`** **`lib32`** **`lib64`** **`libx32`** `lost+found` `media` `mnt` `opt` `proc` `root` `run` **`sbin`** `snap` `srv` `sys` `tmp` `usr` `var` *`swapfile`*

(bold: symlinks, italic: files, rest: folders)

Please help me thanks.

Comment: Just reinstall from scratch, there's no point in recovering anything - it's gonna be extremely time consuming and success is not guaranteed. Maybe give Midnight Commander a try - I've never made such errors in it. I don't quite understand why people insist on using pure console text commands which are far from visual and which are prone to catastrophic errors.

Comment: First time I did something similar to this was 30+ years ago. I think it is a requirement to be a sysadmin that you destroy a system at least once. Back up /home and /etc, then reinstall the operating system. You're bound to miss something if you try to copy directories from a live install to your disk.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I've never seen any gui interface that provides the power and selectivity of the command line. Depends on if you value safety or functionality. A "New Contributor" probably should err on the side of safety.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov what's Midnight Commander

Comment: @doneal24 what's stored in /etc that's important? should i copy the whole folder in the new installation? or what

Comment: Information about mount points, services that should be started at boot, usernames and passwords, sudo authorization, configuration for individual services. The list goes on. Making a copy of `/etc` before re-installing lets you go back and compare options between the new system and the old. And before Artem responds, Midnight Commander is a visual file manager. Google is your friend here.

Comment: how do i compare the options between the old and new system?

Answer (score 0):

First, do not mount the hard drive in read-write mode. The best thing I would advise you to do is to first backup your important data (photos…). Then, try to find the important data (photos…) that has been removed. Tools like photorec (that also recover many file format) may be useful. Note however that it will put all your files in a single folder (you will lose the hierarchy). Finally, once you have everything, just reinstall the system from scratch. Even if it boots, chances are the some important files have been removed, and it could make your system unstable.

Comment: ive backed up my home folder, also can i just copy the whole /usr folder to my new installation? yk for getting some of my apps on the new installation that i had

Comment: @magneticGaMr You've already said that `/bin` is gone. What bits and pieces of the file system outside of `/usr` might also have disappeared? Also, if you installed extra applications, the binaries could be in `/usr` but are there configuration files in `/etc`, log directories in `/var/log`, cache in `/var/lib`, etc. You have to reinstall unless you know all the locations that might have been affected.

Comment: oh, but there might be a lot of stuff that hasnt been deleted because i use a USB as my hard disk cuz the hard disk is broken and usbs are usually slower than a hard disk (i think) and the command ran for approximately 2 secs and not longer, so there's still a chance many of my files are still present?

Comment: also is there a way i can get the list of packages i had installed? maybe apt cached the apt list command somewhere and i ran the apt list command a few days ago, i just want some of my programs back
but its also ok if its not possible

Comment: "_usbs are usually slower than a hard disk (i think) and the command ran for approximately 2 secs and not longer_" that's two seconds to wipe an in-memory version of your filesystem metadata. For a 32GB partition that could easily be most of it. (The system then spends somewhat longer writing the pending changes back to the media.)